# Is "quaver" a blend word of "quake" and "waver"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, nouns, portmanteau-words

Dictionary.com has this [etymology for *quaver*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quaver):

> 1400–50; late Middle English **quaveren**  (v.), **blend of quake  and waver**

But Wiktionary [disagrees](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quaver#Etymology):

> From Middle English **quaveren**, **frequentative form of quaven**, cwavien (“to tremble”), **equivalent to quave +‎ -er**. Cognate with Low German quabbeln (“to quiver”), German quabbeln, quappeln (“to quiver”). **More at quave, quab, quiver**.

Given these differences, I am interested which statement is right.

Comment: Try scrolling down on your Dictionary.com link there. Also, [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=quaver&allowed_in_frame=0) is quite helpful. I'm voting to close since this is easily answered by the Etymonline link.

Comment: The Online Etymology Dictionary, which I would consider more reputable than your two sources, supports the second account: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=quaver&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: Aaand beaten by 25 seconds by @Mahnax...

Comment: Why is etymonline considered a more authoritative source than reference.com? IMO, this is not general reference.

Comment: Good question. +1

Comment: @coleopterist Reference.com cited zero references for that particular "etymology", whereas Etymonline has a rather lengthy [list of sources](http://www.etymonline.com/sources.php?allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: It's also a question that how to judge one dictionary is good or not with one another, I really want to find an introduction of the  recommended dictionary with etymologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quaver:**

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quaver):

> C15 (in the sense: to vibrate, quiver1): from **quaven** to tremble, of Germanic origin; compare Low German **quabbeln** to tremble

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=quaver):

> "to vibrate, tremble," early 15c., probably frequentative of **cwavien** "to tremble, shake" (early 13c.), probably related to Low Ger. **quabbeln** "tremble," possibly of imitative origin.

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quaver):

> late Middle English (as a verb in the general sense 'tremble'): from dialect quave 'quake, tremble', probably from an Old English word related to **quake**.

[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quaver):

> 1400–50; late Middle English **quaveren** (v.), blend of quake  and waver1

Also,

> [C15 (in the sense: to vibrate, quiver 1 ): from **quaven** to tremble, of Germanic origin; compare Low German **quabbeln** to tremble]

[Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quaver):

> Middle English, frequentative of **quaven** to tremble
>
> First Known Use: 15th century

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quaver):

> From Middle English quaveren, frequentative form of **quaven**, **cwavien** (“to tremble”), equivalent to quave +‎ -er. Cognate with Low German **quabbeln** (“to quiver”), German quabbeln, quappeln (“to quiver”).

---

**Quake:** All the sources used above agree that quake stems from O.E. **cwacian** / **cweccan**.

---

Setting aside the uncertainty between Old English *cwavien* and Low German *quabbeln* being the source, it appears to be true that *quaver* and *quake* are related, with, according to ODO, the latter possibly being the source of the former. However, there's no mention of *waver* anywhere besides *dictionary.reference.com*.

Google, on the other hand, points to a couple of sources that lend credence to the portmanteau idea.

Julie Tetel Andresen, [author](http://www.julietetelandresen.com/non-fiction.html) and [associate professor of English (in 1999) at Duke University states](http://www.dukemagazine.duke.edu/issues/25/faculty/3.html):

> The word-formation process du jour in American English is blending, that is, combining two existing words to make a new word. A couple of blends formed in the Middle English period (1150 to 1500) have survived into Modern English, e.g., scrawl (sprout + crawl) and **quaver (quake + waver)**, as well as a couple from Early Modern English (1500 to 1800), dumbfound (dumb + confound) and apathetic (apathy + pathetic).

From the book, [English words from Latin and Greek elements by Donald M. Ayers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0816508992):

> Other blends are smog (smoke + fog), radiclib (radical + liberal), slurb (slum +
> suburb) and its extension slurbia, Comsymp (Communist sympathizer),
> harmolodic (harmonic + melodic), comsat (communications + satellite), simulcast (simultaneous + broadcast), **quaver (quake + waver)**, jargonaut ...

From the book, [A Biography of the English Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0495906417):

> However, among the numerous probable blends from ME are *scroll* from *escrow* + *roll*; *scrawl* from *sprout* + *crawl*; **and *quaver* from *quake* + *waver***.

To conclude, while the (online) dictionaries do not mention the possibility of *quaver* being a *blended* word, there appear to be a few credible sources that do. There are, however, no authoritative sources that support this claim.

I'll be interested to know what the OED says about this.

Comment: "scrawl = sprout + crawl" is a really weird contention.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed etymology list!!It deserve to accept this answer, although the OED is not in it.

Answer (score 4):

The OED traces it, through *quave*, to a hypothetical Old English verb *cwafian*, with the qualification ‘further etymology uncertain, perhaps imitative.’ That's about as close as we're likely to get.

Comment: Thanks for your help with the OED supplement, it's really helpful to know the OE word is hypothetical, just like the PIE root.